# Weird popup/malware showing on my website

Tags: web-hosting, advertising, malware, virus

Can someone please help me figure out what this is? It looks like some ad pops on my website for no reason when opening website through Google search results.

I've tried looking in the code and couldn't find anything wrong. Hostgator also confirmed there is no malware on server and couldn't verify what this is. I have no idea how this got here in the first place and how to remove it.

[image: Screenshot]

If you click 'ok' it takes you to a bovada poker site.

Comment: Disable all your addons in Firefox and then see if you're still getting the same problem. You may want to confirm that the same thing is happening in other browsers. Could be browser hi-jack or spyware on local system.

Comment: This is not computer related as same thing happens on different computers as well.

Comment: Still might be due to a browser add on though... Without seeing the site in question, we have nothing else to go on. The fact you said this happens when you enter your site via Google's search results, this sounds exactly like a browser SERP hijack.

Comment: It happens in different browsers too, sorry for not confirming this earlier.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you navigate to your website directly (rather than via search results)? You'll have to provide a link to the site in order for us to help any further.

Comment: If multiple computers experience this problem then its likelihood that it's malware. From the looks of it and @GeoffJackson has hit the nail on the coffin it looks like a htaccess malware. It's unlikely that hostgator would do a in depth check. Can you please edit your question and give the community more information in order to help you, a URL to the site and the contents of your htaccess file would make this question more constructive as its likely this question will be closed by a moderator or voted closure by the community for not being able to answer the question (not constructive).

Comment: .htaccess looks normal, website is pokercash4free(dot)com

Comment: @rocco: I visited your site both directly and through google and didn't get any popup. As GeoffJackson said if your not experiencing this behavior on multiple computers then your search results might have been hijacked.

Comment: I think this happens only when you visit it for the first time through google.com for a keyword search. Very weird though, what's this results hijacking and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running any Ad campaigns on your website? I have had similar experiences when I used non-adsense advertising platforms. Remove any advertisement code that you are using and it should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

If it is happening when you come from Google then you are hacked. Hackers do this so when you view your site you cannot detect the hack. Look in your .htaccess file for malicious entries as that is where something like this typically needs to go (but it may be elsewhere).

After removing that code you will need to find and fix the security hole that allowed this as this attack is *automated* which means it will be re-installed again and probably quickly. If you're using a third party CMS you need to upgrade to the latest version *immediately* and you need to make sure you follow their security best practices. (I'm guessing you're using Joomla as this is a common attack for Joomla sites).

Answer (score 0):

Google has an entire [help section about identifying and removing malware from your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/163634?hl=en)

Google provides:

- Tools for identifying the malware
- Advice for locking the site down while you are investigating
- Documentation about how to clean the site up
- Suggestions for keeping it secure